# Corda Open Source (トライアル版) とCorda Enterprise (商用版)の違い

Tags: java

Corda Open Source (トライアル版) とCorda Enterprise (商用版)の違いは何ですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ビジネスニーズを念頭に置いて設計されたCordaはOpen Source (トライアル版)が以下のGithubに公開されており、誰でもアクセス、ダウンロード、アプリケーション開発が可能です。

https://github.com/corda/corda

一方、可用性やセキュリティに関する追加機能やブロックチェーン基盤の商用サポートなどの、商用利用を前提にしたシステム開発に必須となる非機能要件の充足とサポートを提供するのがCorda Enterpriseです。

Corda Enterpriseには以下のようなオープンソースのプラットフォームとは異なる機能が含まれています。

1．商用サポート

- 迅速なパッチ提供（セキュリティ対応／バグフィックス等）
- 日本語窓口開設（SLAは要相談）

SBI R3 JapanのCordaに精通した技術チームが日本語で対応します。適宜R3の担当者と連携してサポートします。

- コンサルティングサービス（Professional Service, 有償）

設計や実装に関するコンサルティングサービスや各種レビュー、Cordaでのアプリ開発遂行に必要な技術を学ぶトレーニング、サンプルアプリ提供などを行います。Cordaでのシステム構築のノウハウを持つエンジニアが、お客様のプロジェクトに沿ったベストプラクティスの提供や、よりよいアーキテクチャを探るディスカッションを提供し、お客様の開発期間短縮やリスク低減への貢献いたします。

2．パフォーマンス

Cordaコアをマルチスレッド化し、トランザクションの同時並行実行が可能になります。

3．非機能要件の充実

- App Firewall（Corda Firewall）提供

商用ブロックチェーン基盤で唯一のBlockchainApplication Firewallを提供し、社内システムやクラウド上に1つまたは複数のノードを展開することができます。

- 高可用性を実現

ノードの冗長化構成が可能（非クラスタリング）なので、基盤となるハードウェアに障害が発生した場合、ノードを迅速に回復させることができます。また、Collaborative Recoveryというノード間で発生したトランザクション差異の検出、及び回復をサポートするディザスタリカバリーの機能を提供しています。

- ハードウェアセキュリティモジュール(HSM)をサポート

署名鍵の保持においてより高いレベルのセキュリティを必要とする企業向けに、市場をリードする HSM プロバイダ（例：Azure Key Vault、Gemalto、Altimaco など）とのインターフェイスを提供します。

- ノードのヘルスチェックツール提供

4．その他

- レガシーシステムとの統合

Postgres、Oracle、SQL Server、SQL Azureなどのエンタープライズデータベースをサポートしています。